# jQuery or JS, make element leave the screen on bottom and enter on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'we been searching for solution but couldn't find any similar. As title said, I have navigation absolute positioned on very bottom of screen, but when user reach bottom, I want navigation to "slide down", and show on top.

My logic was to see which screen height user got so I can animate only one css property.

Here's the code I wrote that doesn't work

```
if ( (topDistance-10) < scrollTop ) {
        //Navigation control
        var navHeight = $(window).height();
        $(".navigation").animate({bottom: -64},600).delay(1000).css('bottom' , navHeight).delay( 3500 ).animate({bottom: navHeight - 64},600);

    }
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="navigation stickBottom">
    <li data-slide="1"><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li data-slide="2"><a href="">truth</a></li>
    <li data-slide="3"><a href="">about</a></li>
    <li data-slide="4"><a href="">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.navigation {
position: fixed;
z-index: 3;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);

}

.navigation li{
    color:#fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:26px;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the sample HTML/CSS that goes with the code..?

Comment: Task is quite simple, as soon as user reach bottom hide navigation on bottom and show (as slide down) on top of page

Comment: Hmm I didn't get it... So you have a navigation at the bottom of the page, and once the user reach there, you want to hide and and show the one at top..? are you trying to troll users or am I missing something..?

Comment: ahhaha good point, but that's the task, same navigation disappear at bottom and comes out on top

Comment: So you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/sphB2/11/)..?

Comment: Hmmm thanks TJ but not really this, imagine that you got navigation on bottom of scrren all the time, and when you reach bottom of page, the animation is next.
1. Animate bottom - navigation height
2. See window height and assign that value to navigation bottom property
3. Height of navigation - window height that we assigned in step 2 so nav can show up on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for help, this is what I need

```
// 1. Hide On Bottom
        $(".navigation").animate({bottom: -64},200);

        // 2. Switch to top
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".navigation").attr('style' , 'bottom:' + navHeight + 'px');
        },300);

        // 3. Show on top
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".navigation").animate({bottom: navHeight - 64},200);
        },400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```
var body = $("html, body");
body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing', function() { 
   alert("Finished animating");
});
```

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/hellosze/MMgXu/

Comment: Thank's for help but this is not what I'm looking for, my navigation is fixxed on bottom of the screen, and when we reach bottom of page I want navigation to leave the screen on bottom and comes down from top, beeing fixed to top now.